# Could "jibe with" imply something racist?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, puns, racism

In the latest episode of Succession, they are talking about potential candidates and we know there is a guy called Salgado (I don't remember a prior implication that Salgado is racist but he is not white white as can be deducted from the last name) and this conversation happens:

> Tom: But I also jibe with Salgado.
>
> Shiv: Oh, you "jibe" with him? Pretty sure that's racist, Tom.

Could anyone explain why it could be racist? I thought "jibe with" only means he agrees with his views or something.

Comment: @Cascabel Okay thanks and I searched for it and maybe because I am not a native, I still don't get it. Sounds like jive is something to do with African Americans, but this guy is maybe Latin American?

Comment: I'll write an answer, but will probably get hit for it.

Comment: @Cascabel What worries me is that 'I'm not going to post a real answer on this because I think it is searchable' doesn't warrant a CV on 'no readily available research shown'. No caveats advising caution in major dictionaries. And _any_ word can be touted as a candidate for being taboo.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Hi Edwin. I did not VTC, and actually did post an answer...(the CV is not mine.) Gonna delete that comment...that said, I think when a search is done on _jibe_, the topic of the confuseables usually pops up. Nice to hear from you again.

Comment: To VTCers. The question is about the racist aspects of the usage, not the eggcorns. Either find a duplicate, or post a more suitable answer addressing the issue of racism in such a nuanced usage.

Comment: Shiv's comment is the racist one ... insinuating racism that almost certainly isn't there.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  I hope you are well and in good spirits. Happy Thanksgiving...we have a lot to be thankful for this year.

Comment: @successionfang, and why would Salgado's last name lead to deducing he's not white? The surname is of Portuguese or Galician origin, both in the west of continental Europe.
See https://www.census.gov/topics/population/race/about.html for the official American take on race.

Comment: I agree with @RicardoGMC – my immediate reaction was that Shiv's comment was  either ironic or tongue-in-cheek (depending on whether the character is understood to be smart or not) rather than racist, but the **OP's own statement** that a non-Anglo surname necessarily belongs to a "not white white" person is *demonstrably and absurdly racist*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Jibe*** means "to be in agreement with".

***Jive*** is a verb to describe a silly (or mendacious) way of talking or less often, a frenetic form of dancing. The usage  has its roots in 1930s African-American music.

...and as well there is ***gibe***, which means to taunt or tease.

They are sometimes called confusables, or [eggcorns.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eggcorn)

Your protagonist was making a rather bad play on the words.

Please note that the phrase "shuck and jive"  has been used in the past to describe evasive behavior. Having its origin in African-American speech, it might  [be perceived as racist when culturally misappropriated by
white authority figures such as police.](https://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2012/10/was-it-racist-palin-accuse-obama-shucking-and-jiving/322151/)

See [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/jive-jibe-gibe) for further information.

Comment: ['to jibe' (or BrE 'gybe') is also a sailing term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jibe), meaning to turn 'through'  the wind. ['Jive Talking'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jive_Talkin%27) is a song by the BeeGees, which sounds like it's about lying. The movie 'Airport' included a scene of an old white lady speaking presumably AAVE to some African American passengers and translating for the white people. [But originally](https://www.etymonline.com/word/jive) it was more like [talking cap](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=No%20cap).

Comment: That it was used for both 'AAVE' in general, and a slangy term for 'lying' is a bit disparaging.

Comment: Hi Cascabel, just adding extra details to what I think is the right answer.

Comment: Thanx @Mitch...much appreciated.

Comment: @Edwin  You gotta get off the schtick, man. DVing an answer to a borderline question so to punish the user is becoming very tiresome. The question is valid.

Comment: The demonstrated reasonable research being?  'No caveats advising caution in major dictionaries' (the first three I've checked) is evidence. You yourself addressed the no-research CV issue in the comment you then deleted. I'd rather see 'Isn't _nice_ possibly racist?' questions ditched as soon as possible. Say 'No!' in a comment and C-V.

Answer (score 0):

> Tom: But I also jibe with Salgado.
>
> Shiv: Oh, you "jibe" with him? Pretty sure that's racist, Tom.

Shiv seems to be joking here.

If Salgado is Spanish, he, along with a lot of other Spanish speakers, will [stereotypically pronounce "v" as "b"](https://www.thoughtco.com/pronouncing-the-spanish-b-and-v-3079534#:%7E:text=Key%20Takeaways,the%20lips%20touching%20each%20other.).

Thus "jibe" can be understood as the imitation of Spanish speaker attempting to say "jive".

Thus *"But I also jibe with Salgado."* can be understood as a Spanish speaker's pronunciation of *"But I also **jive** with Salgado."*

(Both sentences are possible.)

Hence, Shiv: Oh, you "jibe" with him? Pretty sure that's racist, Tom.